# Double quotes containing variable not working in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable which contains some text:

```
var=bar
```

I need to inject it *before* the followed pattern: `</VirtualHost>` in `/etc/hosts/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

When the variable contains a *simple word* it works fine:

```
bash-4.2$ sudo sed "/^<\/VirtualHost>.*/i${var}" /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
...
</VirtualHost> 
bar
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I try to assign an Apache config file to `$var` I got this error message:

```
bash-4.2$ var=$(sudo cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/myconf.conf)
bash-4.2$ sudo sed "/^<\/VirtualHost>.*/i${var}" /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown command: `S'
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for answers.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29613573#29613573), especially the section on "Escaping a string literal for use as the *replacement string* in `sed`'s `s///` command".

Comment: Do you really have two `</VirtualHost>` tags, or has one of them an extra slash?

Comment: Without access to the file you are reading in, we can only speculate; but a better solution altogether is probably to use the `r` command in `sed`. I'm guessing the file contains a newline and so the next line of the value gets interpreted as a separate `sed` command.